# Toolstrip font color and font highlighter button

Tags: .net, winforms

I am making a text editor program. I want a button to change text color and a button to highlight the text. I use toolstrip control to make the tool bar. But I don't know how to make it like in wordpad or word. If I use an image, when I change color the color in the button not change. Please give a guide or sample program like this. Thank you.

Comment: as beginning .. better you get googling and seek some code about toolstrip ..

Comment: Hello @matzone, I always search on google before asking. I didn't found anything. So I ask for help.